# How to align a UILabel left or right in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

Im currently building a chatting app and have come across a problem. When ever I try to align the UILabel left or right depending on who sent the message it does not work. I reload the TableView everytime I receive a message but the labels are not being updated. Im using swift 2.0. What else could I try? Or is there another way to do it better?

```
//in cellForRowAtIndexPath
   if message == my own {
      //tried this
      cell.nameOfSender.frame.origin.y = 0
      cell.nameOfSender.frame.origin.x = widthOfScreen
      //And this          
      cell.nameOfSender.center = CGPointMake(95,15)
} else{
      cell.nameOfSender.frame.origin.y = 0
      cell.nameOfSender.frame.origin.x = 0
      //And this          
      cell.nameOfSender.center = CGPointMake(95,15)
}
```

Comment: dont change the frame, keep the frame through the whole cell width, then change the [textAlignment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/textAlignment) property to set the value from enum [NSTextAlignment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSTextAlignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways,

*first* is use the [NSTextAlignment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSTextAlignment) so you can do something like:

```
cell.lblTitle.textAlignment = .Left
```

*Second* one is to create different [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableViewCell) subclasses for each style (Left and Right)

ex:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = indexPath.row
    //ChatCell is a Subclass of UITableViewCell
    var cell:ChatCell
    // Just Random presenter getting the chat for the row
    let chat = presenter?.getChat(row) 

    //Getting info whether the chat sender is me or not and the instances of each custom cells.
    if chat.sender == ChatSender.Me {
       cell = ChatCellSender(title: "Example")
    }else{
       cell = ChatCellReceiver(title: "Example")
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do I set the label position in the MessageCells? and if so in what method?

Comment: In the same cellForRowAtIndexPath.